# Is there a SIMPLE example of How to use buckminster

Tags: java, eclipse, build, build-process, buckminster

I don't understand buckminster at all. Lets say I have a project, and it needs log4j and junit4. How do I get started, what do I need to do, to specify the dependencies and have the dependencies added to my classpath in eclipse. Is there any tutorial which shows how its done?

Answer (score 9):

I found buckminster brilliant, but *terribly* documented (I know, I know, I should contribute).

I was looking for something to build RCP products. I won't talk too much more about that, but I will say what worked for me:

- The "[webinar](http://live.eclipse.org/node/427)" showed me roughly what I could do, and I found myself going back to it a couple of times to start with.
- Try to get your project checked out into your workspace. This involves:

  1. installing buckminster on your Eclipse installation
  2. creating a small CQUERY file, which is 3 lines of XML telling buckminster what to check out.
  3. creating an RMAP file for your projects. I found this [dogfood2.rmap](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/samples/rmaps/dogfood2.rmap) very helpful.

Thankfully, I am able to completely ignore CSPEC files, as they can be inferred from the existing metadata (i.e. from `MANIFEST.MF`, `plugin.xml`, `.product` files. I think it can work of the `.project` and `.classpath` files, but I don't _k_now). Similarly, I would ignore BOM files for now.

Once I had materialized a workspace successfully, I could go on to try and replicate that headlessly.

This [article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sample_headless_configuration_(Buckminster)) I found useful to create an installation for Buckminster suitable for deploying as part of our continuous integration.

At this point, I had a long think about the relationships between the Eclipse projects used to build up the product. We settled on a tree (sic) with two major branches - the product branch and the test branch:

- cquery points to a `build.feature`
- `build.feature` points to a `product` and a `test.product`.
- `product` points to features `foo.feature`, `foo.ui.feature`, `bar.feature`, `bar.ui.feature`. Each of these features point to plugins or features.
- `test.product` points to `foo.test.feature`, `foo.ui.test.feature`, `bar.test.feature`, `bar.ui.test.feature`. Each of these features point to test fragments that can exercise the product plugins.

By "point to", I mean the feature or cquery specifies it as a dependency. (I couldn't seem to get the `Require-Bundle` header in the manifest file to work, so put everything in the `feature.xml`).

I found playing on the command line very helpful at this stage. The `resolve` and `build` commands I found most helpful. I also found setting the [output property](http://www.nabble.com/how-to-change-buckminster.temp-property--td21448059.html) useful here.

Once I could build (i.e. compile) everything successfully, packaging it as a product was the next thing. Using the `perform` command for an action (`create.*.product`) specified in an inferred CSPEC file generated from a .product file was hardly intuitive, but it helped to have a known good product capable of being exported as a product from the IDE.

The last thing I did was to find the `setenv` (I think) command, which helped set the Java version used to compile the code. There are a small number of properties you can set, but this one was the one I needed.

[Other](http://developer.capeclear.com/7.5.1/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.capeclear.eclipse.studiohelp/studio/automation-ant.html) [links](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.buckminster/msg00516.html) [I](http://eclipse-projects.blogspot.com/2006/05/buckminster-for-monkey.html) also found latterly, that look helpful.

Comment: Although a great overview of Buckminster goodness, this does not really answer the question...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your CQUERY and RMAP here?

Comment: Unfortunately @geejay, this was at a previous clients. For these two reasons, regrettably, no.

Comment: Putting a link on a single letter "I" is, at least, sadism! :-)

Answer (score 5):

New Buckminster documentation is being produced right now. The first "rough cut" contains introduction (based on Eclipse '09 talk), RMAP and CQUERY fully explained, details on properties, and versions. These chapters have about 70 pages, and are in near finished form. More chapters and examples to follow. Hope to make a new draft available weekly.

You can get it here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/buckminster/doc/BuckyBook.pdf (6MB).

Answer (score 4):

From: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_Buckminster#Getting_Started

Hello World: [http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Hello_XML_World_Example_(Buckminster)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Hello_XML_World_Example_%28Buckminster%29)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick start on building I recommend the tutorial [Headless Eclipse RCP builds with Buckminster and Hudson](http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_builds/), though it doesn't cover materialization.

As Henrik mentions the [bucky book](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/buckminster/doc/BuckyBook.pdf) aka "The definitive guide" provides good in depth documentation, from concept overview to xml specifications.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions above I would also recommend the section in [Developing Plug-Ins - Continous Integration with Jenkins](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Continous_Integration_with_Jenkins) on [Preparing you plugins](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Continous_Integration_with_Jenkins#Preparing_your_Plug-Ins) as a relatively simple walk-through.